# How to add a new audio track to a video clip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I'm using Blender in the video editing mode and I'm trying to add a different audio track to a video clip than the one it originally comes with. The audio works on its own. The video works with its original audio. But when I add the new audio and delete the original, the new audio won't play even though the video clip is playing just fine. I do have the AV codec set to MP3 though the volume button below that is grayed out. I can change the volume from one, but it jumps right back as soon as I click out. I can, however, change the audio volume in its own properties box but it has no effect. AV-sync is on. File output is set to Xvid. The video is in channel one and the audio is in channel two. The audio is currently longer than the video clip. I intend to add more until the clips match the length of the audio, but this shouldn't affect being able to hear the audio, right? I need to be able to hear as I edit because matching the clips to the audio is the whole point. I'm not sure what else to add. Please use small words; I'm very new at this.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I'm posting this answer to my own question in case someone else has the same problem as I did. If you feel this isn't helpful, please feel free to vote to delete it.

The issue was that I tried adding the video clip to the audio instead of the other way around. Once I reloaded the file and put in the video clip first and then deleted the original audio and added the new audio it worked just fine.